# Set the LinkType for HierarchicalClustering class in WEKA

Tags: java, machine-learning, data-mining, weka

I came across the following documentation for HierarchicalClusterer class in WEKA:

```
public void setLinkType(SelectedTag newLinkType)
```

How do I set the lining type of clusters in this hierarchicalclusterer class to COMPLETE? Th SelectedTag class does not have this value at all.

Thanks
Abhishek S

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the LinkType for Hierarchical Clustering in WEKA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891528/setting-the-linktype-for-hierarchical-clustering-in-weka)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectedTag` class does not have any value for any particular algorithm.

The `Tag` values are defined in the algorithms. You have to *select* them.

Comment: And how could be selected, could be helpful if you can ad some code example.